# ASP.NET CORE & WEB API: Audit Trail or User activity logging

Tags: logging, asp.net-web-api, filter, asp.net-core, audit-trail

I created a UserActivity Logging or Audit trail using `ServiceFilter`. I couldn't use action filter as I need to pass the dependencies.

I successfully logged the activities of the user.

```cs
public class ActivityLog : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    private ILogUserActivityService _service;

    //injecting specified service to insert the log in database.
    public ActivityLog(ILogUserActivityService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Stores the Request in an Accessible object
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        // Generate the log of user activity

        LogUserActivity log = new LogUserActivity()
        {
            // Username. shall be changed to UserId later afteter Auth management.
            UserName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name ?? "Anonymous",
            // The IP Address of the Request
            IpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
            // The URL that was accessed
            AreaAccessed = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(request),
            // Creates Timestamp
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
        };

          //saves the log to database
        _service.SaveLog(log);

        // Finishes executing the Action as normal 
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I can add `[ServiceFilter(typeof(ActivityLog))]` above the controller and this works perfectly.

Database record:

[image]

But now I would like to add more information. I will add one more column named "Description" where I shall be able to enter the description about what the user deleted, what changes he made, what did he add (along with few properties) and so on.

I am expecting something like `Log.information(...)` in Serilog. So how can I achieve such thing?

Comment: I'm a bit late but maybe you can read the implementation that somebody done https://damienbod.com/2017/02/28/implementing-an-audit-trail-using-asp-net-core-and-elasticsearch-with-nest/

Comment: It is bad practice to use HTTP methods in your URL paths. /GetCountries should be avoided